# Address range and sed command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can someone please explain me why does the following line:

```
echo -e "ab\ncd" | sed "3,4 p"
```

yield output:

```
ab  
cd
```

Is it since the lines 3 and 4 are out of the input range?

I'd expect rather an empty output because the input has only two lines while the command was told to examine lines 3 to 4.

Comment: @techraf Yes, sorry the title should obviously be "Address range and sed command". My mistake.

Comment: What is the output you expected, based on your current understanding of `sed`?

Comment: @techraf I'd expect rather no (empty) input because the input have only 2 lines while the commend was told to examine lines 3 to 4.

Comment: I included your comment in the question. Without it it's hard to get what you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to assume sed's `p` command will print only the lines from the specified range. This is not the case by default.

Unless you add `-n` parameter to `sed`, the input pattern will be printed and in effect matching lines will be duplicated.

Consider:

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd" | sed "3,4 p"
```

Will give you:

```
a
b
c
c
d
d
```

Because in your example there are no lines 3-4, you get the first two lines in the output.

---

To print only the lines from the specified range:

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd" | sed -n "3,4 p"
c
d
```

Comment: "Unless you add -n parameter to sed, the input pattern will be printed" - what  do You mean "input pattern"? Is it just all the lines from input?

Comment: A content of the pattern space which comes from input. Yes, in result these are all lines from the input.